# Manipulação de páginas/sites, Windows Phone Silverlight C#?

Tags: c#, aplicação-web, windows-phone

Vejo diversos apps no Windows Phone, que manipulam um site, geralmente são apps dos próprios sites, como por exemplo o do TecMundo.

Ele capta elementos do site e adiciona dentro dos elementos da app, como por exemplo um `Canvas`. E permite também a alteração do css, ou de tags de categorização etc, meus apps nunca fazem integração com a internet pelo fato de eu não saber como fazer, e esse é o próximo passo para me tornar um desenvolvedor avançado, pois já estou quase decorando os métodos internos do Windows Phone rsrs

Sempre quis saber sobre como isso é feito, já procurei bastante, mas não encontrei nada, exceto o blog do Rudy Huyn, que não ajuda muito.

Alguém poderia me dar uma 'luz' de como isso funciona, mesmo que seja no Android ou Ios, pois me daria uma dica de que procurar na linguagem C# do Windows Phone. Sei que a pergunta é meio vaga, mas é porque realmente não sei do que se trata, então qualquer ajuda já seria bastante útil.

Comment: Não tenho muita experiência com desenvolvimento mobile. Mas, se eu fosse você, perguntaria no [Twitter do Rudy Huyn](https://twitter.com/rudyhuyn), ele é bem aberto a responder.

Comment: Creio que ele não responde, mas vou tentar, valeu a dica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possuo um aplicativo que realiza algumas operações simples dentro da página do App. Talves não seja exatamente isso que os sites fazem, mas serve como ponto de partida.

Eu utilizo o controle WebBrowser do WindowsPhone para carregar uma página.
Depois, eu faço invocação de scripts dentro da página através do método InvokeScript.

**Exemplo:**

```
// No Construtor
webBrowser.Navigated += OnBrowserNavigated;

private void OnBrowserNavigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (PreferenciasUsuario.CorFonte == "White")
    {
        // SetFontColor é o nome de uma função javascript dentro da página web
        webBrowser.InvokeScript("SetFontColor", "#FFFFFF");
    }
    else
    {
        webBrowser.InvokeScript("SetFontColor", "#000000");
    }
}
```

**Função Javascript dentro da página Web**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetFontColor(hexColor) {
        document.body.style.color = hexColor;
    }
</script>
```

Abraços

Comment: Valeu, deu uma clareada.. Você sabe como faço para enviar parâmetros para essa página? Exemplo: Um texto para um campo? Ou editar o codigo da pagina?

Comment: Para enviar textos ou manipular elementos não tem muito misterio também não, já que voce vai manipular elementos via javascript. Um dica seria usar o jQuery Mobile para manipular estes elementos.

Comment: Entendo, após eu terminar o app que estou trabalhando vou focar nesse tipo e situação. Valeu pela resposta.

Comment: Depois que seu aplicativo estiver pronto, passa o nome para eu poder instalar e ver ele funcionando, ok? Abraços.